# How to replace None in the List with previous value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to replace the `None` in the `list` with the previous variables (for all the consecutive None). I did it with `if` and `for` (multiple lines). Is there any way to do this in a single line? i.e., List comprehension, Lambda and or map

And my idea was using the list comprehension but I was not able to assign variables in a list comprehension to set a previous value.

I have got a similar scenario in my project to handle `None` in such a way, the thing is I don't want to write 10 lines of code for the small functionality.

```py
def none_replace(ls):
    ret = []
    prev_val = None
    for i in ls:
        if i:
            prev_val = i
            ret.append(i)
        else:
            ret.append(prev_val)
    return ret

print('Replaced None List:', none_replace([None, None, 1, 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, 5, None, None]))
```

**Output:**

`Replaced None List: [None, None, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]`

Comment: You didnt define the behaviour when first item in the original list is `None` therefore it chained at the beggining until appearance of element which is not `None` I guess

Comment: You don't really need `prev_val`.  You can use `ret[-1] if ret else None` to say "use the last element of ret if we've already added something to it, else default to None"

Comment: You consider 0 (zero) as None. Change to: if i is not None

Comment: Note, `if i:` will  be a bug if your list can contain falsey values, e.g. 0. Use `if i is not None`. In any case, this solution is fine. Don't strive to "do things on a single line", strive to write readable, maintainable code. Generally, list comprehensions are for expressing mapping/filtering operations, you won't be able to keep track of previous values cleanly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and balderman that makes sense, I will change it accordingly.

Comment: If you don't want to have this in your main code, put it in a separate module. Way better solution than squeezing everything into one line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Python 3.8 or higher you can do this using the [assignment operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#simplifying-list-comprehensions):

```
def none_replace(ls):
    p = None
    return [p:=e if e is not None else p for e in ls]
```

Comment: Exactly what I want, I aware of `:=` operator but I couldn't find a nice way to use it. It does!

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of lists being mutable

```py
x =[None, None, 1, 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, 5, None, None]
for i,e in enumerate(x[:-1], 1):
    if x[i] is None:
        x[i] = x[i-1]
print(x)
```

**output**

```py
[None, None, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Great! i just simplify it
```for i,e in enumerate(x):
    if x[i] is None:
        x[i] = x[i-1]```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `accumulate()` and the operator `or`:

```
from itertools import accumulate

list(accumulate(lst, lambda x, y: y or x))
# [None, None, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

In this solution you take the element `y` and the previous element `x` and compare them using the operator `or`. If `y` is `None` you take the previous element `x`; otherweise, you take `y`. If both are `None` you get `None`.

Comment: Another best way with `python` library and in one line :) Can you also add the explanation on how the `accumulate` works here, if you get a chance?

Comment: I don't think the first method would produce the same output.

Comment: @MykolaZotko https://repl.it/repls/WonderfulLatePython#main.py

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to do this in a single line? i.e., List comprehension, Lambda and or map

I don't think so because of [the late binding closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures). Besides, it might not be readable.

> I have got a similar scenario in my project to handle None in such a way, the thing is I don't want to write 10 lines of code for the small functionality.

Why do you think it's small? A problem is a problem that needs to be solved. One small function sounds like a good candidate to solve it.

My approach to solve it:

```
def none_replace(ls: list):
    prev, this = ls[0], None
    assert prev is not None, "First arg can't be None"

    for i in range(1, len(ls)):
        this = ls[i]
        if this is None:
            ls[i] = prev
        prev = this or ls[i]

    return ls

print('Replaced None List:', none_replace(['asd', None, None, 1, 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, 5, None, None]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, a terrible one-line version for Python < 3.8:

```
[
    x.__setitem__(i, e if e is not None else x[i-1] if i > 0 else None)
    or x[i]
    for i, e in enumerate(x)
]
```

That I had to break it into several lines for display here probably shows already that this is horribly unreadable and should not be used.

---

`list.__setitem__` returns `None`, so I use an `or` to always return whatever's currently in the list at that location (`or x[i]`). As a side-effect, the `list.__setitem__` sets the i-th element to itself if it's not None, otherwise to the previous value if `i` is not 0, otherwise `None`.

Comment: @ParvathirajanNatarajan Indeed :). It is bad for more reasons than just readability, too, since it modifies the given list in-place (despite looking like it might not, with it being a comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to one of our friend's solutions. slightly modified for readability. Instead of enumeration, use range(len())

```
x =[None, None, 1, 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, 5, None, None]
for i in range(len(x)):
   if x[i] is None:
     x[i] = x[i-1]
print(x)
```

**Output:** `[None, None, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]`

For the first value x[-1] to `None` value. So No errors while executing the program...

Feedback is always appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
   if ls[i] is None:
     ls[i] = ls[i-1]
```

This sets it to the previous variable if it is None.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **generator** to generate proper values. Simply, generators are functions that generates sequence of values and maintain their last state. When generators are called, they are continuing from the last call. We employ this characteristic to access the last visited item in the list. Please see the following code:

```py
L=[None, None, 1, 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, 5, None, None]

def replaceNoneGenerator(L):
    prev_val=None;
    for item in L:
        prev_val=prev_val if item is None else item
        yield prev_val

L1=[item for item in replaceNoneGenerator(L)]

print(L1)
```

**Output**: `[None, None, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2, None, 3,4, None]
print([a[x] if a[x] else a[x-1]  for x in range(len(a))])
```

This definitely ignores the cases where `None` is present at the first place in the list but then handling that shouldn't be a daunting task either.

Comment: Good one though, But what if my list has multiple `None` in-between `[None, None, 1, 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, 5, None, None]`? it would fail to produce the required output